# Change Background Dashed Lines JFreeChart

Tags: java, background, jfreechart

I want to make my chart printible. I know JFreeChart already has a print configuration, but I need to make it printible (black & White) so I can save the image (already printable) in PNG and put that in a report.

I tried changing the background to white, but the dasehd lines in the background become invisible (they are already white).

I searched but I can't find an option to change it's color.

Can someone give me some light?

EDIT: Is a XY chart (originally whith a gray background an white dashed lines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have something like this in one of my sources:

```
plot.setBackgroundAlpha(0.25)
plot.setDomainMinorGridlinePaint(Color.GRAY)
plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.DARK_GRAY)
plot.setRangeMinorGridlinePaint(Color.GRAY)
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.DARK_GRAY)
```

Maybe it helps.

It is also possible to apply a theme like:

```
StandardChartTheme.createJFreeTheme().apply(chart)
```

You could first apply any theme and then modify all the stuff you want.

Comment: Theme seems nice. The code above the plot obect is the chart plot (like chart.getPlot()) ?

Comment: Yop. In your case it should be a `XYPlot` object. (because of the `XYChart`)